# メールのテンプレートの書式設定を保存したまま宛名などを変えたい

Tags: python

win32comでメール自動送付のプログラムを作っていますが、メールの先頭に書く宛名を変えるためにformatメソッドを使いました。

#### コード

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.createItemFromTemplate(temp_path)

mail.body = mail.body.format(name)
#mail.HTMLbody = mail.HTMLbody.format(name)
```

#### テンプレート

---

{}　様
締め切りは**××日**です。
よろしくお願いします。

---

#### 失敗例１

---

〇〇　様
締め切りは××日です。
よろしくお願いします。

---

#### 失敗例２

---

〇〇　様

締め切りは**××日**です。

よろしくお願いします。

---

しかしformatメソッドの直後、テンプレートで設定されていた書式（文字の色、フォント、太さなど）やタブなどが初期化されてしまいました。HTMLBodyの場合、書式以外は初期化され文ごとに一行空けるという不要な改行がされていました。

format以外で宛名など特定の文字列を変える方法はあるのでしょうか？
教えていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: VBAだとこんな記事があるようなので、それをPythonで実現出来れば良いのかもしれません。[リッチテキストなメールテンプレートを開きメールの件名と本文の文言を置換する Outlook マクロ](https://neos21.net/blog/2016/02/23-01.html), [Exporting rich text to outlook and keep formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24245127/9014308)

Comment: Python だけでもメールを送るだけなら実現できそうですが、win32com (Outlook) の使用は必須ですか？ / Python から HTML メールを送る例: [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882712)

Comment: ちなみに「書式（文字の色、フォント、太さなど）」設定が存在してHTMLでは無いのなら、それは`body`や`HTMLbody`ではなく`RTFbody`なのでは？

Answer (score 1):

テンプレートファイル（msg形式）からcreateItemFromTemplateで読み込んでいましたが取りやめ、ソースコード上でテンプレートのHTMLコードを書くことで解決しました。

HTML形式でメールを編集したほうが、フォントなどの設定もできるので便利でした。

```
name = "imbzer"

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.createItem(0)

mail_temp = '''
<html>
<body>
{} 様<br>
締め切りは<b>××日</b>です。<br>
よろしくお願いします。
<body>
<html>

'''

mail.HTMLbody = mail_temp.format(name)
```